# Android styles.xml v14 is not applicable to Android N?

Tags: android, styles, android-7.0-nougat

I have strage issue on beta-build of Android N. I have styles.xml in the values-v14 folder, and for some reasons they are not applicable to Android N. But v22 and v23 are OK. I have no more styles after android v14, so nothing should shadow it. Maybe someone had the same issue ? It is simple to fix, but I can not understand the reason of it.

Comment: @Savchak， please tell me how to fix it. I encounter error when i try to compile apk in Android N. Thanks.

Comment: @mmm2006 I have no compile errors. I have crashes on Android N devices. But it is fixed by creating duplicate of styles.xml from values-v14 in values-v23 folder.

Comment: ok. thanks your help. I will try.